# Измерение времени работы алгоритма в тактах процессора - корректно ли?

Tags: c++

Задача заключается в том чтобы сравнить эффективность работы двух математических алгоритмов с точки зрения требуемого времени/вычислительных ресурсов. Из того что я нашел, предлагается использовать clock(), с помощью которого можно узнать количество тактов процессора, прошедшее с начала программы. Но корректно ли это, с учетом того что параллельно с компилятором процессор используют множество других программ, работающих на ПК в данный момент? Я пробовал измерять количество тактов, требуемых для одного из алгоритмов, и после каждого запуска оно несколько отличается. Может ли функционирование сторонних программ при определенных условиях изменить его существенно (в разы)? 
Есть ли какие то альтернативные способы для измерения времени/количества вычислений требуемых для конкретной программы?
По возможности без сильного углубления в технические детали.

Comment: Вообще-то `clock` считает ну никак не такты процессора, а время... чтобы не писать очень много - советую вам книгу [Гантерота "Оптимизация программ на C++"](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-9908910-6-7.html) - там этот вопрос разбирается очень подробно.

Comment: Он считает такты процессора, прошедшие с запуска программы. Если разделить clock() на CLOCKS_PER_SEC можно получить время, прошедшее с запуска программы.

Спасибо за рекомендацию, книжку гляну.

Comment: Не понимаю тогда, о чем вы спрашиваете - если вы все и так знаете. Кстати, у меня на машине в компиляторе CLOCKS_PER_SEC = 1000, т.е. у меня тактовая частота процессора - 1 кГц, и зависит она только от компилятора, но не от компьютера?...

Comment: Я ориентируюсь на то что написано по этому поводу в интернете. Пример: http://cppstudio.com/post/561/. Остальные сайты в поисковой выдаче дают примерно ту же информацию.
К сожалению, знаю далеко не все. В данном случае не знаю насколько сильно другие программы на ПК могут повлиять на измеренное время работы процессора, также не знаю если какие либо альтернативы clock(). Потому и написал вопрос.

Comment: @BojanGusliar Разве на указанной странице сказано, что это такты процессора? Это просто некий счётчик времени. Счетчик тактов процессорного ядра - rdtsc, но в современных процессорах он тоже не абсолютно надёжен с точки зрения времени исполнения.

Comment: Для измерения производительности программы существует специальный класс программ - профайлеры. Они измеряют как потребляемые вычислительные мощности, так и эффективность работы с памятью, кэшэм,  многопотопчную эффективность.

Comment: `clock()` измеряет время в "условных тактах"  `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`, которых ровно 1000000 в секунду (в них пересчитывают величину  системного таймера).  Как пишут в man clock -- `For improved accuracy, since glibc
       2.18, it is implemented on top of clock_gettime(2) (using the CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID clock)` (которая выдает время затраченное данным процессом и всеми его потоками с наносекундной точностью (другой вопрос, насколько этим нанам можно верить)).

Comment: Действительно, посторонняя нагрузка может влиять на результат (imo в основном из-за влияния на кэши), поэтому каждое измерение времени выполнения будет разным.

Comment: Окей, спасибо за ответы. Попробую разобраться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Советую почитать здесь про разные таймеры:
http://ssd.sscc.ru/sites/default/files/content/attach/310/computerlab1.pdf
- и выбрать подходящий вам. Идеальный таймер вы вряд ли сможете найти, так как многие из них ориентируются на генератор тактовых импульсов. А он обычно динамический, и в каждый момент времени разный. Соответственно, запуская программу каждый раз, вы будете получать разное время.

P.S. Слышал, что можно тактовую частоту зафиксировать, сделать статической. Вроде через BIOS. Но это надо разбираться.

P.P.S. Если хотите что-то более высокоуровневое, советую библиотеку std::chrono. Но насколько она покрывает выше приведённые таймеры - я не знаю.